# make pycaffe -> "fatal error: cublas_v2.h: No such file or directory"

Tags: python, neural-network, deep-learning, caffe

I compiled `caffe` and I know trying to compile `pycaffe`. When I run `make pycaffe` in the `caffe` root folder, I get:

```
f@f-VirtualBox:~/caffe/caffe-master$ make pycaffe
CXX src/caffe/layer_factory.cpp
In file included from ./include/caffe/common.hpp:19:0,
                 from ./include/caffe/blob.hpp:8,
                 from ./include/caffe/layer.hpp:8,
                 from src/caffe/layer_factory.cpp:3:
./include/caffe/util/device_alternate.hpp:34:23: fatal error: 
 cublas_v2.h: No such file or directory
 #include <cublas_v2.h>
                       ^
compilation terminated.
Makefile:516: recipe for target '.build_release/src/caffe/layer_factory.o' failed
make: *** [.build_release/src/caffe/layer_factory.o] Error 1
```

How to fix that?

Answer (score 2):

If you don't plan to use the GPU, you can circumvent the issue by uncommenting `CPU_ONLY := 1` in Makefile.config:

```
# CPU-only switch (uncomment to build without GPU support).
CPU_ONLY := 1
```

Comment: What if we do plan to use GPU?

Comment: @Hack-R Subscribing to the GitHub issue as you did, getting tired of waiting, and eventually switching to some other libraries (which I could easily since I am not doing vision).

Comment: LOL good answer. However, I think I got it working -- had to get the .deb file here `https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-downloads` then install using apt-get. I say I *think* though because it's still currently installing it on my system.

Comment: @Hack-R Cool, if it works, you are welcome to post it as an answer.

Comment: It used up all of my storage memory. I tried to resize the VirtualBox VDI and it became corrupted. 10 hours of work lost. : /  So, I don't know yet if it would've worked.